# Solution verification: finding a Maclaurin series for $f$, interval of convergence, and $f^{(10)}(0)$

Tags: calculus, proof-verification, taylor-expansion

I have to find Maclaurin series for function $f(x)$ = $2x^2\over{16+x^4}$, it's interval of convergence and $f^{(10)}(0)$. I managed to calculate Maclaurin series and $10^{th}$ derivative, but I'm not sure if it's done in proper way and if solution is correct.

---

On determining the series,

$$\begin{align}
f(x) &= \frac{2x^2}{16+x^4} \\
&= \frac{2x^2}{16} \cdot \frac{1}{1-\frac{-x^4}{16}} \\
&= \frac{2x^2}{16} \cdot \sum_{i=0}^\infty \left(-\frac{x^4}{16} \right)^n  \\
&= \frac{2x^2}{16} \cdot \sum_{i=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n \cdot x^{4n}}{16^n} \\
&= \sum_{i=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n \cdot x^{4n+2}}{2^{4n+3}}
\end{align}$$

for $\vert{-x^4\over16}\vert<1 \implies x\in(-2;2)$

---

On determining $f^{(10)}(0)$,

$$f^{(10)}(0)\cdot \frac{ x^{10}}{ 10!} = \frac{x^{42}}{2^{43}} \implies f^{(10)}(0) = x^{32}\cdot \frac{10!}{2^{43}}$$

---

Looking for feedback and opinion if the way I solved it is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your computation of the MacLaurin series of $f$ looks right, but remember that $f^{(10)}(0)$ is a number. You know that$$\frac{f^{(10)}(0)}{10!}=\frac{(-1)^2}{2^{11}}.$$Therefore,$$f^{(10)}(0)=\frac{10!}{2^{11}}.$$

Also, $\left\lvert\frac{-x^4}{16}\right\rvert<1$ doesn't just imply that $x\in(-2,2)$; it is actually *equivalent* to it.

Comment: What happened to x is substituting it with 2 and -2 (what I got from interval of convergence)?

Comment: The series diverges at those two points.

Comment: I’m ahead with the program and doing it Maclaurin on my own, so sorry for tedious questions. To get 10th derivative you input -2 or 2? Is that the way to calculate it?

Comment: To get the $10^{\text{th}}$ derivative, I put $n=2$, so that $x^{4n+2}$ becomes $x^{10}$.

Comment: Does n = 2 have anything to do with interval I calculated or it’s just an accident that 2 will fit?

Comment: It's an accident. I we were after $f^{(6)}(0)$, we would have to take $n=1$.

Comment: That’s all. Thank you very much!

Comment: I'm glad I could help.

Comment: Sorry to bother you but I've done next exercise where function $f(x) = e^{x^2+1}\cdot x$. I calculated Maclaurin series and ended up with $\sum_{i=0}^n {x^{2n+1}\cdot e\over n!}$. How to calculate $100^{th}$ derivative of $f(x)$? Problem is 2n+1 is odd and 100 is even and I'm stucked.

Comment: That's another question. Please post it as such.